# Ubuntu 20.04: apt update gives error for wireguard (2)

Tags: apt, updates

I have the same errors and same system as described in [Apt Update Gives Error for Wireguard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282254/apt-update-gives-error-for-wireguard), however the solutions given there do not work for me for some reason

bash shell output:

```
drusakov@ldn-dr:~$ sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:wireguard/wireguard
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~wireguard/ubuntu/wireguard'.
The team named '~wireguard' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/wireguard'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:

drusakov@ldn-dr:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                          
  403  Forbidden [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Hit:3 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease                                                                                                                                     
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                          
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                  
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                    
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireguard/wireguard/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

drusakov@ldn-dr:~$ sudo apt-get install wireguard
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
wireguard is already the newest version (1.0.20200513-1~20.04.2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

drusakov@ldn-dr:~$ lsb_release -r
Release:    20.04

drusakov@ldn-dr:~$ uname -a
Linux ldn-dr 5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

drusakov@ldn-dr:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

Comment: type in the header: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Go into your sources and remove the PPA manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove wireguard source list manually.

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wireguard*
```

Comment: correct directory: /etc/apt/sources.list.d (with 's' in source's'). Thanks it worked! It is so simple if you know what to do : )

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. Kindly mark answer as accepted.