# Teamviewer repository error

Tags: apt, updates, teamviewer

i am trying to update my Ubuntu 18 while doing so, I am having an error related to Teamviewer, the version is not supported. I am not able to solve the problem even after removing Teamviewer from the installed software, still I have this error after updating:

```
Err:7 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                  
  403  Forbidden [IP: 54.192.105.21 443]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: Failed to fetch https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 54.192.105.21 443]
E: The repository 'https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Kindly help to resolve the error.
Thank You,

Comment: There is no such version as Ubuntu 18. There is an 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt Update Gives Error for Wireguard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282254/apt-update-gives-error-for-wireguard)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue yesterday, had to remove the repository:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list*
```

Then `apt` did not throw errors anymore:

```
sudo apt update
```

---

You can also remove the software:

```
sudo apt remove teamviewer
```

and/or reinstall from the [`.deb` package](https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb) provided on the [official homepage](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) to get the newest version.

Previously, during installation, `teamviewer` installed their repo via `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list` file which does not work anymore. The repository does not get installed anymore, so you won't receive automatic updates.